# Exclusion keyword in maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, project, pom.xml

what does exclusion keyword do in maven.

In a module if a dependency(X) depends on dependency(Y). In parent pom version of Y included is 0.1 but X wants to use version 0.9 of Y. Will exclusion be useful for x in this case.

If X adds exclusion of Y, does it mean that X will not include Y which is available by itself but would include the required version of Y by itself(according to its pom file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusions are used to exclude transitive dependencies, eg

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

in this example we include spring-context.jar in our project but we dont want commons-logging.jar it uses because we want to use slf4j.

As for "parent pom version of Y included is 0.1 but X wants to use version 0.9 of Y" it is enough to add version 0.9 to X pom and it will override parent's version